# Multiple different hover behaviours

Tags: html

So i have table which tds have set background images. When I hover over td I want to change background image. I know 2 ways of doing this, in css with different classes or ids, or in js, again with ids.
I would like to know what is optimal solution, since I can't put hover effect inside html tag.

Note: I am not lazy, just want to reduce the code. [Here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSFu7.png)

Comment: Use css(unless the table is massive and you don't want to add so many classes), are you having issues with this or just needed an opinion?

Comment: I agree. If `CSS` does what you need, don't use `JS`. Not only is it ultimately simpler but you don't have to worry about over protected browsers that don't allow scripts or prompt the user to allow them.

Comment: @Huangism Sorry if I made myself unclear, I know how to do it, just interested in finding out if there is better solution, and if not which is most optimal of two mentioned.

Comment: @Alex ok then my first comment after edition answers that

Comment: @Huangism Yes, but you also mentioned the issue I am having. Let me rephrase, is there a way to do what I want, without calling classes for every td. If not, than you answered my question, by telling me CSS is better.

Comment: @Alex yes you can do it without class/id on all of the `td`s. You can utilize js and data attribute so when you hover, you simply grab the data attribute which will have your bg image name or full path(whatever you want to use) and apply it to the hovered td. But you will have to add the data attributes in the html

Comment: Maybe you should add some code to show the ways you already know about. A working snippet would be a nice thing to start with for the ones who want to help you. :)

Comment: @Huangism can you elaborate?

Comment: @Alex you would have something like this on the td `<td data-bg="something_useful"` then when you hover the td, you grab that data attribute and use the value you set to set the bg. The value can be the name of the image or the full path or whatever you want as long as it works with your js

Comment: @Huangism yeah, I think I understand now, will try that. Thanks :D